# How to add a custom built framework in my iOS project?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I kept the framework's .xocdeproj file in my project folder. Then I dragged and dropped the customFramework.xocdeproj file into the root of my project. Afterwards, I added my framework in **Targets -> ProjectName -> General -> Frameworks, Libraries and Embedded Content** -> Plus button, and the added my custom framework.
But when I import it in my module, error of **"No module named..."** occurs.
Kindly guide if am missing any step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add your framework to your project, and add your *.framework file to project

[image: Add file to project]

After that go to the project inspector, and go to "Framework, Libraries, and Embedded Content". Set the embedded property to Embed & Sing on your framework

[image: Embed property]